# Возможно ли запустить функцию, которая записанна в файле html, в файле js

Tags: javascript, html

Я только учусь программировать на js, поэтому не бейте, пожалуйста, тапками за тупой вопрос.

[image: html]

В этом HTML файле есть тег скрипта с функцией. Я бы хотел запустить функцию используя сторонний js файл. Возможно ли это?

Comment: «Я только учусь программировать на js, поэтому не бейте, пожалуйста, тапками за тупой вопрос.» - 
1) Здесь в основном все учаться, 2) Плохих вопросов не бывает

Answer (score 1):

**Да.** Твои js файлы увидят функции (второе название - методы) на открытой странице и смогут вызывать их.

Главное, чтобы в функциях были данные уже готовые для обработки, когда будет происходить вызов.
И главное чтобы вызов функции происходил после загрузки этой самой функции.

То есть надо чтобы сначала эти данные с функцией первые были в списке загрузок, а только после был вызов. То есть последовательность создай. Иначе будет ошибка в консоле DevTool или тишина.

*Ты же не сможешь пнуть мяч, пока он до тебя не долетит.* Так и с функциями, что пока она не прогрузится, ты её не вызовешь из другого файла или места страницы.

И корректнее вызывать что-то после полной загрузки DOM (если проще, то после полной загрузки страницы):

1. на vanilla js (чистый js) - window.addEventListener('load', function(){ здесь ваш код })
2. на jquery -  $(document).ready(function(){ здесь ваш код })